# Why does semantic-release backmerge fail with HEAD -> develop (non-fast-forward)?

Tags: git, rebase, semantic-release

I'm using [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) with [saitho/semantic-release-backmerge](https://github.com/saitho/semantic-release-backmerge).

The branch structure looks like this: `release <- beta <- alpha` The branches `alpha`, `beta` are pre-release branches and `release` is the stable branch.

The usual flow works fine:

- commits are merged into `alpha`
- `alpha` is merged into `beta`
- `beta` is merged into `release`

The problem occurs when merging a hotfix into `release`. In that case, `semantic-release-backmerge` should:

- rebase the `beta` branch onto `release` (so that hotfix is also in `beta`)
- rebase the `alpha` branch onto `beta`  (so that hotfix is also in `alpha`)

The backmerge plug-in only works if all branches are already on the same commit and I make a commit on the `release` branch. But it doesn't work in the following example:

1. All branches are on same commit
2. Make commit on `alpha`
3. Make commit on `beta` (e.g. a hotfix)
4. Backmerge fails with error:

```
! [rejected]        HEAD -> alpha (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<REMOVED>'
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

How is it possible that a simple use-case like this doesn't work with the backmerge plug-in? How can I resolve that in the context of semantic-release-backmerge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, rebase works by copying some old commits (which are not necessarily *bad* but are now outdated) to *new and improved* commits:

```
             F1--F2--F3   <-- feature
            /
...--o--o--o   [shared point]
            \
             o--o--o   <-- mainline
```

becomes:

```
             F1--F2--F3   [abandoned]
            /
...--o--o--o
            \
             o--o--o   <-- mainline
                    \
                     F1'-F2'-F3'  <-- feature
```

where the 3 `F` commits are the ones that make up the feature branch.  Note that the original commits are still in the repository: we just no longer *use* them, since we have Git find a commit by starting from a *name* like `mainline` or `feature` and then working backwards.

#### That's just *your* repository

This happens successfully in the repository in which you *run* `git rebase`: the old commits are now ejected off the tip of the branch, and the new and improved commits make up the new tip of the branch . But if and when you want to `git push` these new-and-improved commits, they *automatically mean the receiving Git will see you as "behind"*. You *are* "behind": you *discarded* the old commits `F1-F2-F3` in order to put the new and improved commits on.

So, in the repository to which you're running `git push`, *they* might now have:

```
             F1--F2--F3   <-- feature
            /
...--o--o--o
            \
             o--o--o   <-- mainline
```

They receive the three replacements and see that you'd like to have *them* move *their* name `feature` to point to `F3'`.  They immediately object: *Hey, if I do that, I'll lose someone's valuable commits `F1-F2-F3` off the end of my branch.  You probably want to get those commits from me and merge them in first, right?  Right?!?*

You don't, of course: you *threw out* the three feature commits in favor of the new and improved ones.  But *they* don't know that.

Note that it's possible that *they* now have:

```
             F1--F2--F3--F4   <-- feature
            /
...--o--o--o
            \
             o--o--o   <-- mainline
```

in *their* repository, if some third person added a new commit `F4` to the feature branch and used `git push` to (successfully) send it back to the repository you are all using to communicate with each other over on GitHub.<sup>1</sup>

Now, if that *didn't* happen—and most of the time it indeed did not happen—then you might want to "force" this communications-repository (on GitHub) to take the same change to its `feature` branch.  To do that, you can use `git push --force-with-lease`.  This uses your own Git repository's memory of their Git repository's `feature`, stored in your `origin/feature`, to know that the last time you polled the sharing repo, `F3` was the *last* commit on `feature`.  This means `F3'` should be the last commit, as it is in your rebase.  *If they are still in that state* at the time you run `git push --force-with-lease`, you will tell them that, yes, you really would like them to eject *their* `F1-F2-F3` chain off the end of *their* `feature` branch please, because `F1'-F2'-F3'` is your shiny new improved replacement chain.

If they *did* acquire a new `F4` on the end, your `git push --force-with-lease` will find that, no, they don't end at `F3` any more, and *won't* force them to toss `F4` off the end of their `feature`.  Your `git push --force-with-lease` will fail.

The tricky part here is that this might not be the *only* reason your `git push --force-with-lease` could fail.  (Perhaps, for instance, your Robotic Rebaser lost its push access somehow: perhaps some admin messed up a permissions change.)  But *if* the failure is because `F4` appeared, you should obtain the new `F4` commit and put your `feature` back over to the new `F4` and have the robot try again, this time copying `F4` to new and improved `F4'`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "on GitHub" here because you mentioned:

> `failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<REMOVED>'`

It doesn't actually matter *where* this meeting-point repository is, though: what matters is the potential for losing a commit like `F4`, which occurs whenever there's a race between whatever is doing this rebase, and some additional person making additional commits.

---

#### Making it all work under all conditions is hard

In a previous $workplace someone borrowed an existing Robotic Replacer and adapted it for our own needs.  Some bugs cropped up (I forget which ones) and we worked on them and got around the usual case and had something usable for our purposes.  It still wasn't perfect but it did what we wanted, most of the time, and didn't spiral into an infinite loop of repeated failed rebases in bad situations.

Overall this is a hard problem, made harder by the lack of an "evolve" concept in Git (this concept exists in Mercurial, but as an extension, and it also depends on the fact that Mercurial commits *aren't* wholly immutable, unlike Git commits).  But the most common case is pretty easy: you just have to know how to automate it.

When doing this on GitHub, remember that GitHub actions by default have *shallow* clones these days; you'll need one deep enough to complete the rebase correctly (how deep that will be depends on many factors and the only really safe way to do it is the expensive full-clone way).

Comment: Your git answers are just legendary, thanks